# How to disallow zip files on CentOS?

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload, ssh, centos

I was wondering if there is a way to disallow archive file types (examples: zip, rar, etc.) in CentOS through .htaccess. I'm currently using an upload script that is not secure and as a temporary fix I'd like to stop people from uploading any type of files that hold a collection of files.

Or even better I'd like to only allow specific files to be uploaded (jpg, etc.) through .htaccess. That way it's limited to an account and not the whole server.

Comment: Nope. Secure the script.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the file extension of the file during the upload and discard any unwanted files.

Further, you could check the type of the file using [finfo_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) method.

**Edit:**

Further, if you need more security you can call [imagecreatefromgif()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php) or [imagecreatefromjpeg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) or [imagecreatefrompng()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) which will try to create image resource from the uploaded file. This will save you from the problem mentioned by Procyon82.

Example taken from 4th comment by [Schraalhans Keukenmeester](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php#75275)

```
if (!$img = @imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfilename)) {
  trigger_error('Not a GIF image!',E_USER_WARNING);
  // do necessary stuff
}
```

Comment: From what I understand you could still hide harmful code inside an allowable file. Am I seeing this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the file for uploading.

```
$upld = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$mime = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE),$upld);
```

Check mime type from FILEINFO

```
if($mime=='image/gif'||$mime=='image/png'||$mime=='image/jpeg'){

  $info = getimagesize($upld);
  $tmp = explode('/',$info['mime']);
```

Check valid image. Open from GD

```
  $im = call_user_func_array('imagecreatefrom'.$tmp[1],$upld);

  if($im){
    # Its valid image, no error
  }else{
    # Its not valid or damaged images
  }
  # Its not image (zip, mp3, txt & etc.)      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the filename is in the URI or query-string itself, htaccess isn't going to help you. In fact, you should't be trying to find a transport solution for an application problem. You need to fix this in your upload script.

The htaccess file doesn't do anything about uploading files.

Comment: What about a server setting through SSH?

Comment: @Procyon82 no, you need to fix the script, there exists no "server settings" to prevent a script from creating a file with a certain name (ending with .zip).